# Raspberry Pi - suddenly no SSH access

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Today I've noticed I can't connect to my raspi anymore using SSH with "Connection refused" or "...actively refused". It's extremely strange as far as until now, for a long time there was no problem accessing it through SSH. My raspi is actually running on wifi, I can ping it, I can HTTP access it, all the services seem to be running (I've got a streaming server on, PHP, apache, mysql - everything ok). I also have several config scripts reachable by HTTP requests, which are working normally. I have created a new set of ssh keys using

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ssh-server
```

then disabled and enabled ssh again via raspi-config, but nothing seems to work. Strange thing I've also noticed, that overnight, my router appended another IP address to my pi for some reason (despite that my IP lease time is set to forever on my wifi router), but I have no clue how this could affect my SSH access (maybe someone has some idea...?).

Important thing of this case is, that even if I try to locally (hdmi, keyboard, mouse) execute

```
 ssh pi@raspberrypi
```

I still get "connection refused on port 22", I have no firewall and no other security stuff enabled and my router is set to forward SSH.

Actually, I can only access my raspi locally, not via network. I'm completely stuck. Any ideas? Tks.

Comment: What does `sudo netstat -tlpn | grep 22` say?

Comment: ...does not say anything at all, it just executes and shows nothing....

Comment: So the service is not running. `sudo apt-get purge ssh-server` and reinstall maybe?

Comment: it says Unit ssh.service entered failed state. Defined-by: systemd, says also ssh.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start. What should I do? how to reinstall? I'm  a newbie and have really very brief experiences with linux.

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge ssh-server` (uninstall with purge) and `sudo apt-get install ssh-server`. The `purge` is to remove config files that may be broke.

Comment: Also, I think you can ask this question on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Package 'ssh-server' has no installation candidate. Also when trying to purge it says "Virtual packages like ssh-server can't be removed"

Comment: On some systems the package is called `openssh-server`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some systems the package `ssh-server` is called `openssh-server`.

```
sudo apt-get purge openssh-server
```

uninstall with purge, and:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

The `purge` is to remove config files that may be broke.

Comment: I was having a different issue where I could SSH locally, but remote wasn't working after some Wi-Fi IP changes. The fix was to purge and install like you specified. No clue what was going on there.